# WCF Post Json from angular

Tags: c#, json, angular, wcf

I am trying post method to send json data to wcf from angular. Angular is sending the data in json format but wcf receiving it as null object. Can get method be used to send json. GetData methos is being called on a button click event.

## Angular component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {


  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient){

  }


  getData(){
    this.httpClient.post('http://localhost:3292/examservice.svc/jsontest',{
      RollNumber: '41',
      Name: 'Test'
    })
    .subscribe(
      (data:any) => {
        console.log(data);
      }
    )

  }
}
```

## WCF Service.svc.cs

```
namespace Service
{

    public class Service : IService
    {
        public Student jsont(Student s)
        {

            return s;
        }
   }
}
```

## WCF IService.cs

```
namespace Service
{

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService
    {

[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "jsontest", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
        Student jsont(Student s);
    }


    [DataContract]
    public class Student
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string RollNumber { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove `BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest` then you are good to go.